# What is the performant way of checking a string in array of 10million strings?

Tags: javascript, performance

string to be checked for presence is a domain name (google.com) in a list of 10 million unique domain names of const type inside browser. Either I can concatenate 10million into 1 string so it is a problem of checking substring or I can use array index of to check the index.

This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1473742/2752107 and other related questions but does not address the scale.

Comment: What exactly do you want to check? If it's in the list? If some substring of it is in the list? Anything else? If it's just presence, then building a HashSet is the best option if you have to repeatedly check for presence of a String.

Comment: Is "checking a string" finding if the string is in the array?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on multiple factors.

Is the array sorted in any way? If so, perhaps something like a binary search is your best bet.

Do you want to find a specific string in an unsorted array and quit the loop once you have found it? you're probably best of using `Array.prototype.find()` or creating a for loop and breaking as soon as you have found a string.

Do you need to check every string in the array? A simple for loop can do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> Either I can concatenate 10million into 1 string so it is a problem of checking substring or I can use array index of to check the index.

Checking for a substring is slower than checking it using indices.

As [Rezaa91's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64232037/9253414) suggests, if you can order the array, you can then perform a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) which would be *way* faster than a linear search.

If you do want/need to search linearly, however, use a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) so your website/application remains usable and responsive while the search is in progress.

Comment: I think @joachim Sauer's answer of using Set is better because it is O(1). I can create sorted array. I am not sure if javascript Set is backed by TreeSet or HashSet.